# Generating a PDF with form answers in NodeJs and send it by email

Tags: html, node.js, forms, pdf, puppeteer

I'm on a personal project which is a simple form with many inputs to be filled.

The last step is to confirmed the datas, once this is done, **I would like to generate a PDF of the form answers and send it to an email that I asked for before** (in the form).

I tried Puppeteer, it generates the PDF of the template of the form, but the variables are not filled.

I would like to do something like "When the confirmed button on the recap page is clicked, then generate the PDF with the datas on the page."

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("http://localhost:8888/Medical%20Form/recup_donnees.php", {
    waitUntil: "networkidle2",
  });

  let button = await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector("#test");
  });

  await page.waitForSelector("button");

  await page.click("button");

  await page.pdf({ path: "bordeeeeeeeel.pdf", format: "a4" });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Here is my code, even if I know it is absolutely wrong (because it loads an empty page), I can't figure it out how to make it works, maybe I'm going the wrong way with Puppeteer and I should take something else to do the trick.

Sorry for that noob question, but I'm actually a noob...

And thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you are expecting other users to fill out the form and then have their input created in a `PDF`, and then sent in an e-mail, I'd definitely think that using a programming language and `PDF` library to handle that. It appears that you are posting to a `.php` file, so if you have the ability to use `PHP` then for this scenario I wouldn't recommend that `puppeteer` be used.

I'm sure there is a scenario or way that `puppeteer` would be great, but you would have to be given the data for `puppeteer` to input and submit on the form.

The other option would be that the forms/data has already been submitted and you are able to see it on the website, where you would then instruct `puppeteer` to fill the form fields with the data and then screenshot the page and save as `.pdf`.

If you like the idea of using a server-side language like `PHP` to handle this, perhaps [take a look at this example](https://mpdf.github.io/real-life-examples/user-input.html) using the `mPDF` library in `PHP`.

Comment: Hey mate, thank you so much for your answer. I will take a look to the mPDF because yes I collect all the datas in recup_donnees.php (so everything is well displayed on the final page)

I try your solution right now! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Treckstar, I went for MPDF wish seems to be more efficient for what I want. But, as a big noob I'm blocked on many stuffs.

Here is "my logic" (which could be not logical at all ahah)

**1. The user fills a HTML form**

**2. All the informations he submitted are gathered in a PHP file that is acting like a "datas confirmation page", here is the page :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Récapitulatif</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./donnees.css" />
</head>
<body>
       <div class="container">
   <form action="mypdfgenerator.php" method="post">
   <h1>Informations générales</h1>
   <ul id="infos">
       <li><span>Nom :</span> <?php echo $_POST['Nom']?></li>
       <li><span>Prénom :</span> <?php echo $_POST['Prenom']?></li>
       <li><span>Adresse :</span> <?php echo $_POST['Adresse']?></li>
       <div class="cp-ville">
       <li><span>Code Postal :</span> <?php echo $_POST['code-postal']?></li>
       <li><span>Ville :</span><?php echo $_POST['Ville']?></li>
       </div>
       <div class="telephones">
       <li><span>Téléphone domicile : </span><?php echo $_POST['Teldom']?></li>
       <li><span>Téléphone bureau : </span><?php echo $_POST['Telbur']?></li>
       <li><span>Portable : </span> <?php echo $_POST['Portable']?></li>
       </div>
       <div class="date-age-sexe">
       <li><span>Date de naissance :</span> <?php echo $_POST['date-naissance']?></li>
       <li><span>Age :</span> <?php
 $dateNaissance = $_POST['date-naissance'];
 $aujourdhui = date("Y-m-d");
 $diff = date_diff(date_create($dateNaissance), date_create($aujourdhui));
 echo $diff->format('%y').' ans';
?></li>
       <li><span>Sexe :</span> <?php echo $_POST['Sexe']?></li>
       </div>
       <li><span>Email :</span> <?php echo $_POST['Email']?></li>
       <li><span>Profession :</span> <?php echo $_POST['Profession']?></li>
       <li><span>Adressé et/ou recommandé par :</span> <?php echo $_POST['Recommandation']?></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <h1>Raison de la visite</h1>
   <ul>
       <li><span>Raison de la visite :</span> <?php echo $_POST['Raison']?></li>
       <li><span>Date approximative du dernier examen dentaire (ou soins dentaires) :</span> <?php echo $_POST['dernier-examen']?></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <h1>Questionnaire de santé</h1>
   <ul id="sante">
       <div class="reponses-QCM">
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Etes-vous en bonne santé ? :</span> <?php echo $_POST['sante']?></li>
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Troubles cardiaques :</span> <?php echo $_POST['cardiaque']?></li>
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Troubles vasculaires/sanguins :</span> <?php echo $_POST['vasculaire']?></li>
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Troubles rénaux :</span> <?php echo $_POST['renaux']?></li>
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Troubles digestifs :</span> <?php echo $_POST['digestif']?></li>
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Troubles hépatiques :</span> <?php echo $_POST['hepatique']?></li>
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Troubles nerveux/épilepsie :</span> <?php echo $_POST['epilepsie']?></li>
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Troubles pulmonaires / asthme :</span> <?php echo $_POST['asthme']?></li>
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Troubles oculaires :</span> <?php echo $_POST['oculaire']?></li>
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Diabète :</span> <?php echo $_POST['diabete']?></li>
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Rhumatisme articulaire aigu :</span> <?php echo $_POST['rhumatisme']?></li>
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Arthrose (préciser zone) :</span> <?php echo $_POST['arthrose']?></li>
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Troubles cutanés :</span> <?php echo $_POST['cutanes']?></li>
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Allergies :</span> <?php echo $_POST['allergies']?></li>
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Troubles glandulaires/hormonaux :</span> <?php echo $_POST['glandulaire']?></li>
       <li class="sante-li"><span>SIDA / HIV+ :</span> <?php echo $_POST['SIDA']?></li>
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Hépatite :</span> <?php echo $_POST['hepatite']?></li>
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Tuberculose :</span> <?php echo $_POST['tuberculose']?></li>
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Cancer :</span> <?php echo $_POST['cancer']?></li>
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Autre maladie(s) ? :</span> <?php echo $_POST['autres-maladies']?></li>
       </div>
       <div class="traitement-medical">
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Suivez-vous un traitement médical en ce moment ? :</span> <?php echo $_POST['traitement-medical']?></li>
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Si oui, pour quelle(s) raison(s) :</span> <?php echo $_POST['raisons-traitement']?></li>
       </div>
       <div class="medicaments">
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Prenez-vous des médicaments ? :</span> <?php echo $_POST['prise-medicaments']?></li>
       <li class="sante-li"><span>Si oui, lesquels :</span> <?php echo $_POST['quels-medicaments']?></li>
       </div>
   </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <h1>Renseignements complémentaires</h1>
   <ul>
       <div class="cigarettes">
       <li><span>Etes-vous fumeur ? :</span> <?php echo $_POST['Fumeur']?></li>
       <li><span>Si oui (cigarettes/jour) :</span> <?php echo $_POST['cigarettes-jour']?></li>
       <li><span>Depuis (années) :</span> <?php echo $_POST['duree-fumeur']?></li>
       </div>
       <div class="radio">
       <li><span>Avez-vous été traité par radiothérapie ? :</span> <?php echo $_POST['radiotherapie']?></li>
       <li><span>Si oui, date et localisation :</span> <?php echo $_POST['date-radiotherapie']?></li>
       </div>
       <li><span>Avez-vous eu des saignements prolongés après une extraction chirurgicale ? :</span> <?php echo $_POST['saignements-chirurgicaux']?></li>
       <li><span>Etes-vous sous traitement par biphosphonates ? (ex : Aclasta® , Actonel® , Fosamax® , Fosavance® , Bonviva® ,Optruma® ,...) :</span> <?php echo $_POST['biphosphonates']?></li>
       <div class="infos-medecin">
       <li><span>Nom du médecin traitant :</span> <?php echo $_POST['medecin']?></li>
       <li><span>Adresse du médecin traitant :</span> <?php echo $_POST['adresse-medecin']?></li>
       </div>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="validate">
<button type="submit" id="test"> Télécharger en PDF </button>
<button> <a href="./index.html"> Retourner au début </a></button>
   </form>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**4. Then I want him to click on the submit button at the end, and when it does, it triggers the mypdfgenerator.php page which is this:**

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

$html ='<html>
<body>
    <div>Nom '.$_POST['Nom'].'</div>
</body>
</html>';

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

I'm trying to get only the first variable to test but **it is not displayed in the PDF.** (the DIV element is well displayed as I see the static text)

I know this looks like not logical or correct at all for you guys but for the moment, I'm completely stuck with it...

A big thanks to you, I would love to help others too, and of course I will when I'll be able too

Have a good day!

Comment: Little update, I was complicating my own life, I delete the mypdfgenerator.pgp page to put everything directly on the recup_donnees.php page, and it works!

If someone has a similar problem, don't hesitate to ping me I could help!